# What is the point of nop in CIL

Tags: c#, cil

So I wrote the following code in C#.

```
class Test
{
    int a;
    System.IO.StreamReader reader;

    public Test()
    {
        a = 5;
        reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(String.Empty);
    }
}
```

And the constructor of the class in IL looks like this

```
.method public hidebysig specialname rtspecialname 
        instance void  .ctor() cil managed
{
  // Code size       33 (0x21)
  .maxstack  8
  IL_0000:  ldarg.0
  IL_0001:  call       instance void [mscorlib]System.Object::.ctor()
  IL_0006:  nop
  IL_0007:  nop
  IL_0008:  ldarg.0
  IL_0009:  ldc.i4.5
  IL_000a:  stfld      int32 Test2.Test::a
  IL_000f:  ldarg.0
  IL_0010:  ldsfld     string [mscorlib]System.String::Empty
  IL_0015:  newobj     instance void [mscorlib]System.IO.StreamReader::.ctor(string)
  IL_001a:  stfld      class [mscorlib]System.IO.StreamReader Test2.Test::reader
  IL_001f:  nop
  IL_0020:  ret
} // end of method Test::.ctor
```

There are 3 `nop` commands. (Which as I know stands for no operation). What is the need of those commands. I mean what would be the difference if there was no command at all instead of `nop`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

They are used by the C# compiler when it writes the .pdb file for your program.  Which contains debugging info, which includes file+line number info for your code.  The debugger uses this to find the machine code where it needs to inject an `INT 3` instruction to get the program to stop executing when you set a breakpoint.  The jitter emits a NOP machine code instruction for each Opcodes.Nop in the MSIL.

The first nop is used when you set a breakpoint on `public Test()`.  Note that it is injected *after* the base constructor call so that the *this* variable becomes valid in the Auto/Locals/Watch debugging windows.

The second nop is used when you set a breakpoint on the first { curly brace.  That line generates no code at all so there's a hard need for a fake MSIL instruction.

Same story for the third nop, generated for the last } curly brace.  When you set a breakpoint on that one then you can inspect the method return value (if any).  Visible indirectly in the Debug + Windows + Registers window.  Improved in VS2013.

So this just aids in debugging your program, they make breakpoints act predictably.  Those NOPs are *not* generated when you build the Release configuration of your program.  One big reason why a C# project has a Debug and a Release configuration.  You can still debug a Release build, it is however a pretty confounding experience that makes you doubt your sanity :)

Answer (score 3):

They are used to support breakpoints when building in debug mode and will make no difference to the execution of your assembly.